# StackExchange.Redis not reading responses on heavy load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

We are using the StackExchange.Redis library in a big ASP.Net Core Web-API project and have some performance-issues on heavy load.

Even though the reading and writing to Redis using this library works just fine during occasional requests, the library completely stops processing redis-responses on heavy server loads.

To reproduce the issue we've written a minimal test service.
This is our API-Method in the ASP.Net Core Controller-Class:

```cs
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer _client;

        public TestController(ConnectionMultiplexer client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        [HttpGet("many")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
        {
            var database = _client.GetDatabase();

            Console.WriteLine("-- StringSetAsync");
            await database.StringSetAsync($"testkey:{Guid.NewGuid()}", "test").ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine("-- -- Return");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And we're connecting to our single Redis server using:

```cs
var client = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions {
    EndPoints = { { "10.200.1.100", 6379 } },
    AbortOnConnectFail = false,
    ConnectTimeout = 15000
}, Console.Out);
```

Output during occasional requests (as expected):

```
-- StringSetAsync
-- -- Return
-- StringSetAsync
-- -- Return
-- StringSetAsync
-- StringSetAsync
-- -- Return
-- -- Return
...
```

Output on heavy load (`wrk -t8 -c400 -d60s --latency http://localhost/api/test/many`):

```
-- StringSetAsync
-- StringSetAsync
-- StringSetAsync
-- StringSetAsync
-- StringSetAsync
<<< Forever until we kill the request-spamming with wrk >>>
-- -- Return
-- -- Return
-- -- Return
-- -- Return
-- -- Return
```

We can see in Wireshark that Redis is responding to the SET commands instantaneously but it looks like that StackExchange.Redis doesn't read the incoming TCP responses and therefore the async StringSetAsync never completes.

Also the application starts consuming more and more memory because of thousands of Tasks waiting for their completion.

We tried some debugging and this line https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/PhysicalConnection.cs#L716 is never reached during the request-spamming until we stop wrk. Then it is executed many times until all Redis-Responses have been processed.

This bug doesn't occur when executing many parallel Redis-Commands using a while/for loop manually, so we think that it is somehow related to the asynchronous ASP.Net Core Method execution.

**EDIT:** As suggested by Orel Eraki we've tried to reproduce this with synchronous API-Methods and the issue persists.

```
[HttpGet("sync")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var database = _client.GetDatabase();

    Console.WriteLine("-- StringSet");
    database.StringSet($"testkey:{Guid.NewGuid()}", "test");
    Console.WriteLine("-- -- Return");

    return Ok();
}
```

We're using version 1.2.4 because that's the one included in ASP.Net Core, but we can reproduce it with the latest release 1.2.6, too.

We've already reported this issue against the library, but nobody seems to care there. https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/826

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 1. What version of StackExchange.Redis you are using ? 2. Is this reproduce in the non async version as well ?

Comment: @OrelEraki Thank you for the tip. I've edited my question.

Comment: Did you take a memory dump of the not responding process and have a look at that? procdump -ma pid c:\temp\NotRespondingRedis.dmp. Loading the dump into Visual Studio an Paralell Stacks could already lead to some clues.

Comment: Don't call `.ConfigureAwait(false);`. first, ASP.NET Core handles the synchronization differently (unlike ASP.NET) and second it's only recommended to do that in 3rd libraries where you're not sure in which context the action will be executed at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed during the major Rewrite of some communication Code in the 2.0 release.
Please see the linked issue and the release notes for more information:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/871