# StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.StringSetAsync stops setting data in cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

Stackoverflow!

Please, help me to find an error in my services. The story:

I have very simply .net 5 console app that periodically makes web request to external resource and stores data in Redis cache via StackExchange.Redis so at any moment the cache contains actual value.

```
internal class TimedService : BackgroundService
{
    readonly ILogger<TimedService> _logger;
    readonly IServiceScopeFactory _services;
    readonly RedisStore _redisStore;

    public TimedService(
        ILogger<TimedService> logger,
        IServiceScopeFactory services,
        RedisStore redisStore)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
        _redisStore = redisStore;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await UpdateBinanceRates();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    async Task UpdateBinanceRates()
    {
        using var scope = _services.CreateScope();
        var binanceAdapter = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBinanceRatesAdapter>();

        var rate = await binanceAdapter.GetPriceAsync(Currency.USDT, Currency.BTC);
        if (rate.IsFailure)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Unable to receive rate from binance.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var settingResult = await _redisStore.SetObjectAsync(RedisSharedKeys.BinanceKey, rate.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            if (!settingResult)
                _logger.LogError($"Unable to cache Binance rate");
            else
                _logger.LogInformation($"Binance rate updated");
        }
        catch (AggregateException aex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(aex, "Exception while caching Binance rate");
        }
    }
```

Where SetObjectAsync is an extension method:

```
    public static async Task<bool> SetObjectAsync<T>(this RedisStore cache, string key, T value, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)
    {
        var stringValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        return await SetStringAsync(cache, key, stringValue, timeSpan);
    }
```

and

```
    public static async Task<bool> SetStringAsync(this RedisStore cache, string key, string value, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)
    {
        return await cache.RedisCache.StringSetAsync(key, value, timeSpan);
    }
```

RedisStore injected as a singleton:

```
        services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            var redisSettings = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RedisSettings>>();
            return new RedisStore(redisSettings.Value);
        });
```

My other service gets the cached data. Everything works fine after service starts, but about 12 hours later the service stops store data in the cache - service works, but i see no data in cache (i use RedisInsigth-v2 to check the cache). Also, there is no error in logs that means that RedisCache.StringSetAsync returns true all times and no exception throwed. I'm using "StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.2.4" and Redis v6.0.6 in Docker. Interesting, that with other keys rarely saved in Redis i dont have any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably encountering an exception somewhere in `UpdateBinanceRates`, most likely when you are trying to hit Redis on that string set, it's probably a timeout or something, it's possible it's some json convert issue impossible to say for certain given the nature of this issue.

You aren't seeing it because you are trying to catch an `AggregateException`. Most likely the exception is getting out of `UpdateBinanceRates`, and because your while loop isn't wrapped with any kind of try/catch the exception escapes and your background service just dies (hence no more updates). You might try wrapping the inner part of the while loop with a try/catch with a very generic exception (probably just `Exception`) to see if the next time you encounter this behavior if it is an exception escaping. That's most likely your problem.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the background service continues working without any problem. I found similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191898/stackexchange-redis-not-reading-responses-on-heavy-load. Trying to solve it.

Comment: you was absolutely right, the exception was in UpdateBinanceRates, thank you!